# Why can't I calculate route for trucks via Croatia, Lithuania, Latvia, Estonia?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

I see, that API Here does not allow to plan route for trucks across Croatia, Lithuania, Latvia and Estonia.
You can see it in example: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/route_with_tce by setting vehicle specification to "Trailer truck (40t)".
You can't calculate route e.g. from "Ljublana A1" to "Zagreb A2" ("Couldn't reach way point 1"). But if you change "total length" parameter below 1200 - the route is calculated. This is motorway, so there is no extra length limit.

It looks like a bug (invalid maximum length of vehicle with trailers for this countries implemented on Here side), because trucks with trailers up to 16,5m long are allowed to drive in all EU countries.

Another example: this is how route from Slovenia to Montenegro is calculated for 16,5m long truck with trailer: [Route from Slovenia to Montenegro with length=16,5m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQr8l.jpg).
It is insane, because trucks actually drive through Croatia. And it is enough to change length to 12m to get proper route via Croatia.

Comment: Just a guess: Did you try this yesterday? Some countries don't allow trucks to drive on Sundays.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but yes, I've checked on weekdays and weekends and I was randomly changing filtering by datetime - all the same.